# Why "job_manager" did not submit some of the jobs?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I tried to submit around 2000 circuits with "job_manager", and it turns out that some jobs are not submitted. Please see the code and error message below. I understand that we can submit max 5 jobs at a time, so it is not surprised to get the WARNING, but those jobs should be submitted when the previous ones are finished. Also please note that the "experiment 375" (the one triggers the error message) is not failed, but it is not submitted at all.

I also checked the job history, see the screenshot below. Indeed, "L_3_vqe_qc_5" was missed, and never submitted afterwards, which exactly corresponds to the 375th experiment. Is there any way to avoid this?

Many thanks for the help!

(EDIT: A bit of search leads to me the "timeout" error discussed here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/1169. Has this issue been solved?)

(EDIT2: See the post [Why did "job_manager" submit the same job twice and how to fix it?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15578/why-did-job-manager-submit-the-same-job-twice-and-how-to-fix-it/15579#15579), for a workaround of the issue here.)

```
# Need to transpile the circuits first.
qclist = transpile(qclist, backend=backend)

# Use Job Manager to break the circuits into multiple jobs.
job_manager = IBMQJobManager()
job_set = job_manager.run(qclist, backend=backend, name='L_3_vqe_qc')


result_qc = job_set.results()
result_qc = [ result_qc.get_counts(ind) for ind in range(len(qclist)) ]
print( result_qc )
```

and the error message is

```
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:07:26,619: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f01db16bee437192eab7 to finish before submitting the next one.
/Users/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedjob.py:133: UserWarning: Unable to submit job for experiments 375-449: 'Timeout while waiting for job 6003f01db16bee437192eab7.'
  warnings.warn("Unable to submit job for experiments {}-{}: {}".format(
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:12:27,968: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f01db16bee437192eab7 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:13:32,341: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f022c4547b677c533108 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:17:32,482: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f02a9110da92007c4c14 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:18:36,084: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f0319110dadeec7c4c15 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:20:12,296: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f037c4547b774953310b to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:24:15,390: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f1a9b16beeb3de92eac4 to finish before submitting the next one.
/Users/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedjob.py:133: UserWarning: Unable to submit job for experiments 825-899: 'Timeout while waiting for job 6003f1a9b16beeb3de92eac4.'
  warnings.warn("Unable to submit job for experiments {}-{}: {}".format(
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:29:17,112: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f1a9b16beeb3de92eac4 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:29:44,659: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f2992159c385a834e9bc to finish before submitting the next one.
/Users/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedjob.py:133: UserWarning: Unable to submit job for experiments 975-1049: 'Timeout while waiting for job 6003f2992159c385a834e9bc.'
  warnings.warn("Unable to submit job for experiments {}-{}: {}".format(
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:34:45,966: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f2992159c385a834e9bc to finish before submitting the next one.
/Users/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedjob.py:133: UserWarning: Unable to submit job for experiments 525-599: 'Timeout while waiting for job 6003f2992159c385a834e9bc.'
  warnings.warn("Unable to submit job for experiments {}-{}: {}".format(
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:39:47,453: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f2992159c385a834e9bc to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:43:01,237: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f2d9cf834acf2a506bb9 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:43:57,144: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f338b16bee9d0892eace to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:45:06,760: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f42ccf834a050f506bc7 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:50:02,826: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f5762f13a0c4006406c1 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:52:24,291: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f8924ae4e577be32c9a2 to finish before submitting the next one.
/Users/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedjob.py:133: UserWarning: Unable to submit job for experiments 1500-1574: 'Timeout while waiting for job 6003f8924ae4e577be32c9a2.'
  warnings.warn("Unable to submit job for experiments {}-{}: {}".format(
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 00:57:25,735: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f8924ae4e577be32c9a2 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:01:09,173: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f8cbcf834a4441506bef to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:01:53,181: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003f910cf834a4424506bf2 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:02:35,367: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fa384ae4e5712332c9b1 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:03:18,686: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fac6b16bee172792eb14 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:04:29,024: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fcd32f13a0533b640708 to finish before submitting the next one.
/Users/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedjob.py:133: UserWarning: Unable to submit job for experiments 1950-2024: 'Timeout while waiting for job 6003fcd32f13a0533b640708.'
  warnings.warn("Unable to submit job for experiments {}-{}: {}".format(
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:09:30,436: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fcd32f13a0533b640708 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:09:54,575: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fcfe2159c3caa234ea17 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:10:38,221: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fd299e0e7f25ffb32405 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:11:21,017: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fd542f13a0689b64070c to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:12:03,256: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fd984ae4e536e332c9d2 to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:13:10,995: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003fee0b16bee44e092eb3a to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:13:53,037: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003ff0bb16bee98bf92eb3c to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:14:36,193: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003ff36b16bee443992eb3f to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:15:18,779: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003ff602159c3817c34ea2f to finish before submitting the next one.
managedjob._async_submit:WARNING:2021-01-17 01:16:01,750: Job limit reached, waiting for job 6003ffa44ae4e50f2032c9e5 to finish before submitting the next one.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-229aa73320ab> in <module>
      8 
      9 result_qc = job_set.results()
---> 10 result_qc = [ result_qc.get_counts(ind) for ind in range(len(qclist)) ]
     11 print( result_qc )

<ipython-input-50-229aa73320ab> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8 
      9 result_qc = job_set.results()
---> 10 result_qc = [ result_qc.get_counts(ind) for ind in range(len(qclist)) ]
     11 print( result_qc )

~/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedresults.py in get_counts(self, experiment)
    125                 be found.
    126         """
--> 127         result, exp_index = self._get_result(experiment)
    128         return result.get_counts(exp_index)
    129 

~/psi4conda/envs/env_for_qiskit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedresults.py in _get_result(self, experiment)
    226         (job, exp_index) = self._job_set.job(experiment)
    227         if job is None:
--> 228             raise IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable(
    229                 'Job for experiment {} was not successfully submitted.'.format(experiment))
    230 

IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable: 'Job for experiment 375 was not successfully submitted.'
```

[image]

Comment: Can you actually submit more than 900 circuits for a particular job? I thought 900 was the maximum circuits allowed for a particular job.

Answer (score 1):

This might has to do with the fact that you can only submit 900 circuits in a particular job.

[image]

and since you are trying to submit 2000 circuits, this might be a problem. What you can do is split these circuits into different jobs.

Comment: I had the same issue, I have 1500 circuits in total, but it looks like the system divides the list into a series of jobs, each of them has 75 circuits

Comment: @Zhengrong were you using Valencia? I think that machine has max_circuit of 75

Comment: I used melbourne.

Comment: @KAJ226, If it is due to the limit of number of circuits, then I don't think the job will be submitted at all. Since some of the jobs were submitted, and some were not, I tend to feel that it is because of the timeout issue: job_manager will wait for 5 minutes to submit the next job, after that the job will be omitted. Right now, I will resubmit the missing jobs again, and recombine the results....

Comment: @KAJ226 For melbourne, the max number of circuits are 75. What is the machine in your screenshot?

Comment: @fagd it was Melbourne. I might have requested for a research account so that is why the max circuit is 900. https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/researchers-program/

Comment: @KAJ226 I don't know we can do that!! Do we have access to "Manhattan" with such account? That would be extremely useful!

Comment: I don't think you can get access to Manhattan (maybe there is a way to do that...) but you get to request for reservation and such.

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to the size of the circuits, as Job Manager will divide the circuits into multiple jobs for you (the main reason to use Job Manager).

This is related to the limit of 5 active jobs per backend. If the limit is reached, Job Manager waits for the "oldest running" job to finish. Based on the error message you received, it looks like this issue: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/issues/737, where the wait times out after 5 minutes and the job is never submitted. The fix was included in Qiskit 0.22 (or `qiskit-ibmq-provider` 0.10).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, in both of my questions. I will check my qiskit version...